# PyQt Exit Code 139 Stacked Widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qstackedwidget

A little background: I am creating a script to run data collection and provide the UI/tasks for a research study. Primary libraries being used throughout are Pygame, PyQt5, and threading, plus a few minor utility libraries.

I am running into an issue where my script exits on switching to a new widget in the stacked widget. When I reach around 18 widgets in, the script shuts down with exit code 139 (Interrupted by SIGKILL).

For reference, I am using this as a base for the stacked widget and fading: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Fading%20Between%20Widgets

The transition between widgets on the stack follows the format below with some minor differences between functions. These functions are directly in the stacked widget class shown in the above link.

```
def setInitFixation(self):
    self.addWidget(InitFixation())

    self.setCurrentIndex(1)
    self.setCurrentWidget(self.widget(1))

    self.widget(0).deleteLater()

    self.currentWidget().nextButton.clicked.connect(self.setNextWidget)
```

Another piece that may be affecting it is part of the script launches 3 classes which all use Pygame for their implementation.

Comment: why pygame?????

Comment: Quick and easy to build the tasks for the experiment which were effectively short games anyways.

Comment: you can not mix libraries that need an eventloop, PyQt can not be used together with PyGame, they will block each other.

Comment: I haven't had any issue with that? When one is running, the other isnt being used anyways. Blocking calls between the two haven't been an issue.

Comment: As for the eventloop of Qt ?, you could provide a [mcve] of your problem, not your project.